# Building a Microsoft Word report with VB6?

Tags: ms-word, vb6

I'm building a report out of VB6 in Microsoft Word. I've come across a few issues that seem out of place as I'm working with an already existing report. I'm using the existing report as a reference and building my own. The issues I come across are with text inside the headers. I'm including an image. Additionally, when I do a break page and try to start in row 1, range 1, 1 - the bottom border gets lost for some odd reason. Here is my code....

This is how I pass values to the function below function:

```
w_Wrd.Selection.InsertBreak wdPageBreak -- page break here, header appears on new page with no bottom border
w_Wrd.Selection.Goto wdGoToBookmark, , , "\EndOfDoc"
w_TblRow = 1
Set w_Rng = w_Wrd.Selection.Range
Call TableStyle_001_HeaderLine(w_TblRow, "Client Information")

Private Sub TableStyle_001_HeaderLine(row As Integer, Col1Txt As String)
w_Doc.Tables.Add w_Rng, 1, 1

w_Wrd.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
With w_Wrd.Selection.Tables(w_DocTblIdx).Rows(row)
    With .Shading
        .Texture = wdTextureNone
        .ForegroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorGray15
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderLeft)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderRight)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderTop)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
    End With
    With .Borders(wdBorderBottom)
        .LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
        .LineWidth = wdLineWidth050pt
        .Color = wdColorAutomatic
   End With

'WRITE THE DATA 'comment
    .Cells(1).Select
    w_Wrd.Selection.Font.Bold = True
    w_Wrd.Selection.TypeText Col1Txt
End With

End Sub
```

Image of my header:
[image]

So as can be seen in the image, the left, top and right borders appear fine, however, the bottom border is lost. PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

The alignment of text within a table cell is set by Paragraph formatting. It would also help you to learn to work with Word's objects, rather than using Selection.

```
'WRITE THE DATA 'comment
Dim rngCell as Word.Range
Set rngCell = .Cells(1).Range
rngCell.Font.Bold = True
rngCell.Text = Col1Txt
rngCell.Paragraphs(1).Alignment  = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

Something that may help you with your struggles is to use Word's Macro Recorder. Record performing an action, such as centering text in a cell, then look at the VBA code. Usually you can take this pretty much "as is" into VB6, following the pattern of the code you already have. Although it's usually a very good idea to weed out "Selection" and "ActiveDocument" as much as possible, replacing them with more exact objects.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to overemphasize what a poor idea it is to rely on Word Automation in real programs.

[Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757#/en-us/kb/257757) goes into many of the issues, but from the perspective of server-side code.  However most of those caveats apply to *any* program diddling Office externally in such a manner.

Seek alternatives.

Comment: This is a legacy VB6 application. It's not about building a new process/alternative in this situation, but rather creating a new report based on user's requirements.